# Page loading progress value

Tags: smoothstate.js

Is there a way to know the current loading progress of a page ? What I'mean is that smoothState.js would return a value from 0 to 100% when its loading a page. I would need this info to show a loading bar.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use this:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent

Here's an example:
 - https://github.com/englercj/jquery-ajax-progress/blob/master/demo.html